# Alert when orientation is changed

Tags: orientation, uialertview

Im making my first app in xcode. I have set my supported interface orientation only to potrait. However, in one view I want to show an alert if the iphone is turned to the left (landscape left). Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: Sure there is. What have you done so far?

Comment: Tried UIInterfaceOrientation *interfaceOrientation;
    
if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) with alert view in the if-statement. But that doensn't work. I can imagen that i need some sort of observer. But dont really know where to put it.

Comment: Apple changed how orientation changes are handled in iOS 6. So implementation is different for iOS 6 and iOS 5. What versions are you targeting?

Comment: Ok, i'm targeting iOS 6.1